# How to test if a function asserts in a NEAR smart contract (AssemblyScript)?

Tags: nearprotocol, assemblyscript

I have a function in my NEAR smart-contract (AssemblyScript) that I want to test. I want to test if the assertion actually happened.

AssemblyScript

```ts
foo(id: string): boolean {
  assert(id != 'bar', 'foo cannot be bar');
  return true;
}
```

Unit test ([as-pect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@as-pect/assembly/v/2.7.0#usage))

```ts
describe('Contract', () => {
  it('should assert', () => {
    contract.foo('bar'); // <-- How to test assertion here
  })
});
```

After running the above test, the console logs says

> Failed:
> should assert - foo cannot be bar

I know I can return `false` or `throw` instead of doing an `assert` for the above example, and I may do that instead if it makes testing easier.

Answer (score 0):

use `toThrow()`

Like this:

```
describe('Contract', () => {
  it('should assert', () => {
    contract.foo('bar').toThrow('foo cannot be bar');
  })
});
```

you can also use `not.toThrow()` to test not trowing:

```
  it('should assert', () => {
    contract.foo('foo').not.toThrow();
  })
});
```